# How to use Unity and recreate ObjectContext every request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unity-container, idisposable

I have some problem with IoC - Unity.

I made a simple web app. It consists of one Table "Post" which have three fields: PostId, title, Text. I use generic repository:

```
    public abstract class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        protected ObjectContext db = new BlogDbEntities();

        /* CRUD */
    }

    public class PostRepository : BaseRepository<Post>, IPostRepository
    {
        public void Search(Expression<Func<Post, object>> predicate) 
        {
          /* some search specific entity logic */   
        }
    }

    public interface IPostRepository : IBaseRepository<Post>
    {
        void Search(Expression<Func<Post, object>> predicate);
    }
```

int that repository as you see i create new BlogDbEntities - ObjectContext.
And in controller i use IPostRepository, controller is very simple:

```
public class PostController : Controller
    {

        IPostRepository postRepository;

        public PostController(IPostRepository postRepository) 
        {
            this.postRepository = postRepository;
        }


        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            postRepository.All.ToList();
            return View();
        }


        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            postRepository.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

    }
```

And in Global.asax i resolve dependencies with Unity:

```
 var container = new UnityContainer();
            var controllerFactory = new UnityControllerFactory(container);
            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
            container.RegisterType<IPostRepository, PostRepository>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

After starting application when i do request for example /Post/  first request executed normally. But when i try to execute request again i get Exception **"The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection."**

When i try to execute request without Unity IoC framework exception not displayed and ObjectContext work normally.

**I guess that cause of that behavior is Unity, i think that context stored in Unity Container. Who can help me how to properly configure Unity with recreating context after each request.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Who can help me how to properly configure Unity with recreating context after each request.

When you register the type, you can specify that you want to use a [TransientLifetimeManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.transientlifetimemanager.aspx), which causes each call to create a new instance.

Comment: I think technically you want a per request lifetime manager, rather than transient. Transient gives you a new instance every time you have a dependency, whereas per request would give you the same one as long as you're in the same HTTP request. The latter is usually what you want. PerRequest doesn't ship in the box, but there are lots of implementations out there.